# Obtener imágenes a partir de una carpeta y mostrarlas automáticamente

Tags: html, imagen, script

Quisiera crear en mi HTML un script o algo similar para que identifique las imagenes que se encuentren en una carpeta local y las muestre en mi HTML, no se si esto es posible, pero quisiera informarme de las opciones posibles.

Comment: podes usar la API FileReader que te permite elegir un archivo o varios (es usada en muchisimas webs donde debemos subir archivos) y podes restringir los tipos a solo imagenes por ejemplo, y usar FileReader.readAsDataURL() para obtener los links de las imagenes y cargarlas dinamicamente en el DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En html puedes utilizar la etiqueta `<img>` para añadir imágenes a tu web, `img` te permite indicar donde se encuentra la imagen, ya sea en una carpeta local o en una dirección web.

Para tomar la foto de una carpeta local usa lo siguiente:

`<img src="images/dinosaur.jpg">`

Donde el atributo `src` será la dirección de tu imagen, ten en cuenta que esta es una ruta relativa, por lo tanto la carpeta imágenes deberá estar en el mismo directorio que la el documento html. También ten en cuenta que necesitas poner el nombre de la imagen exacto y con su extensión exacta.

Para utilizar una imagen de la web se utiliza el mismo atributo `src`:

`<img src="https://www.example.com/images/dinosaur.jpg">`

Ten en cuenta que `src` es sensible a modificaciones por lo tanto si cambias la imagen de directorio o el html de directorio también tendrás que cambiar la ruta en tu código html. En el caso de que importes la imagen de un sitio web, si la imagen es eliminada, no se mostrará en tu página.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)